# Automatic GCP user id change

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a very strange issue with Google cloud platform. I have a GCP account managed by my organisation and through this account, I have access to 3 development projects. However, I do not get directed to SSO login while trying to login to this account. A few weeks ago, when I tried to login to this GCP account, I was directed to SSO login but when I logged in, I could not see the development projects that my organisation had added me to, even the default project had changed. However, when I look under the list of accounts (top-right), I could see an additional account - the original GCP account ID with **gtempaccount.com** added to the original account ID. This **gtemp** account has all the development projects intact but I do not get directed to an SSO login although I do get the message - THIS ACCOUNT IS MANAGED BY YOUR ORGANISATION on the **gtemp** account as well. How can these automatic changes to my account be explained?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that, during the few weeks transition period that you mentioned, your organization has switched to a Google Service which caused the creation of this conflicting account. More details on this [thread](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7044710?hl=en).

Within the same thread, you may find hints to your situation and ways to resolve it. I would also suggest reaching out to the Super Admin to see what changes could have happened in between this time.

Finally, if nothing works, then I suggest reaching out to the support team for your Cloud Identity provider to verify what is happening with your account and why you are not being redirected for the SSO sign-in should that still persists.